# How to downgrade Office version on mac

Tags: microsoft-office, macos-highsierra

I have fallen victim to a Microsoft bug (not a virus but a bug) which resulted in an undesired upgrade of my Office software. The bug and the solution are described [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Microsoft-AutoUpdate-for-Office-for-Mac-offers-incorrect-version-updates-a898022e-e80a-4c8d-9aa4-01cff9983037?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US). The solution is to move Word, Excel, Powerpoint and Outlook to trash and then re-install Office 2008.

I have moved those files to trash but now when I attempt to install Office 2008 the installer fails saying Office 2008 can't be installed on this disk - a newer version is already installed.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you backed up all your docs templates etc? and then tried removing all Office 2008 components / folders etc And then re-try the installation process.

Comment: @Solar Mike: I was trying to avoid that, but will do if nothing simpler comes up. I'm not actually a regular mac user so simple sounding steps like "backing up docs templates etc" are quite a challenge and I'm worried I will make a mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I have an additional external drive. I Moved the Office 2008 directory to the external drive as a simple (and easy to reverse) back up, then disconnected the drive. Now the installation works.